# how to sort xsl with following format

Tags: xml, xslt

How to sort current xml to show contents of Html1,Html2.. based on their precedence1,precedence2.. and xml is..

Need to show htmls according to their precedence .. please suggest..

```
  <params>
    <param>
    <name>html3</name>
      <value>Sun Flowers</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>precedence2</name>
      <value>15</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>html4</name>
      <value>Vera Wang flowers</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>html2</name>
      <value>Rose flowers</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>precedence3</name>
      <value>20</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>precedence4</name>
      <value>25</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>html1</name>
      <value>Fairtrade Flowers</value>
    </param>
    <param>
      <name>precedence1</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </param>
  </params>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(name, 'precedence')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

To push the params that do not have a precedence to the end, do:

```
<xsl:sort select="starts-with(name, 'precedence')" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(name, 'precedence')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```